# Strange segmentation fault in mpi C

Tags: c, file, mpi, openmpi

im writing this program with MPI in C. The problem is that in a specific point the program crash and I can't understand why, beacuse im only increase a variable.

```
 for(int tmp=0;tmp<sizeof(how_much_word)/sizeof(how_much_word[0])-1;tmp++){
                cum_sum += how_much_word[tmp];
                printf("Cumulative sum: %d \n",cum_sum);
                printf("AFTER CUM SUM");
                if(cum_sum > lowerbound && partition > 0 ){
                    strcpy(path,"/myfolder");
                    strcat(path,file_name_and_number_words[tmp]);
                    printf("name of file: %s \n",path);
                    file = fopen(path,"r");
                    printf("Opening the file: %s \n",file_name_and_number_words[tmp]);
                    start = how_much_word[tmp] - (cum_sum-lowerbound);
        
                    if (start < 0){
                        start = 0;
                    }

                    printf("Start reading: %d \n",cum_sum);

                    while((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
                        if(isalnum(ch)!=0 ){
                            in_word =1;

                        } else{
                            if ((ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch== '\n') && (in_word==1)){
                                word_count++;
                                in_word=0;
                                if(word_count >= start){
                                    partition--;
                                }
                            }/*end if tabulazione*/
                        } /*end else*/
                    } /*end while*/
                    printf("While is over with partiton: %d",partition);
                    
                } /*end if*/
                fclose(file);
            }/*end for*/
```

Array has got 2 element, file_name_and_number_words has got "mytxt.txt" and "mytxt2.txt", the array how_much_word, has got the number of words for those file, so in this case 6 and 18.
The program crash BEFORE the printf "AFTER CUM SUM", but I can't understand what is wrong.
The output of the crash is:

```
Cumulative sum: 6 
[979208abf4bc:26041] *** Process received signal ***
[979208abf4bc:26041] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[979208abf4bc:26041] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[979208abf4bc:26041] Failing at address: (nil)
[979208abf4bc:26041] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3ef20)[0x7f49630daf20]
[979208abf4bc:26041] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x4)[0x7f496311a254]
[979208abf4bc:26041] [ 2] Compiled/partitioningtest.out(+0x1950)[0x555784fc1950]
[979208abf4bc:26041] [ 3] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7f49630bdb97]
[979208abf4bc:26041] [ 4] Compiled/partitioningtest.out(+0xcca)[0x555784fc0cca]
[979208abf4bc:26041] *** End of error message ***
```

It is a problem with the path of file (I can't verify, beacuse i can't do anything after the cumsum increment)? The variable path is declared in the main (outside the process with rank 0). The declaration is char path[2100]. I used this variable inside the master too, but i think it's not a problem beacuse every process should have a different memory area.

Edited: the array has been sent by the process with rank 0 and recived in this way `MPI_Recv(how_much_word,sizeof(how_much_word)/sizeof(how_much_word[0]),MPI_INT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&status);`

Comment: Please show what `how_much_word` is. If a pointer, you *cannot* find the array length by that means.

Comment: After `file = fopen(path,"r");` you *must* check `if(file == NULL)` and take action.

Comment: please edit your question with a [mcve]. If not, build your app with `-g 0O`, get a stack trace, and get where it crashed (and the content of the local variables) with a debugger.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet im compiling with a json command in vs code, can you help me to understand where I have to insert the parameter -g 0O? the command is: "command": "mpicc -g ${fileDirname}/${fileBasename} -o Compiled/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out && mpirun --allow-run-as-root --mca btl_vader_single_copy_mechanism none -np ${input:np} Compiled/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.out"

Comment: `-g` should be good enough. The next step is to get a stack trace from a core file.

Comment: My guess: `fclose(file);` out of the `if` scope that assigns it with `file = fopen(path,"r");`. If the branch condition doesn't trigger, your program ends trying to close a `null` file handle.